# Has Isaiah 27 verse 6 been fulfilled through Israel's export of "Fruits."?

Tags: isaiah

In the book of Isaiah at chapter 27 verse 6 (NIV), a prophecy is recorded and it is written that,

> In days to come Jacob will take root,
>
> Israel will bud and blossom
>
> and fill the whole world with fruit.

I understand from this  [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agriculture_in_Israel), that Israel exports fruit all over the world.

Because Israel exports fruit all around the world,can one conclude that this prophecy has been fulfilled, or is the prophecy speaking about "spiritual fruit." [Please read here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Galatians%205%3A22-23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considered in isolation it would probably be easier to see it as metaphor, perhaps for general prosperity. However, a few chapters later there certainly seems to be a prophecy that the normally barren land would erupt into a paradise:

> Isa 35:1  The wilderness and the dry land shall be glad; the desert
>   shall rejoice and blossom like the crocus;  Isa 35:2  it shall blossom
>   abundantly and rejoice with joy and singing. The glory of Lebanon
>   shall be given to it, the majesty of Carmel and Sharon. They shall see
>   the glory of the LORD, the majesty of our God.  Isa 35:3  Strengthen
>   the weak hands, and make firm the feeble knees.  Isa 35:4  Say to
>   those who have an anxious heart, "Be strong; fear not! Behold, your
>   God will come with vengeance, with the recompense of God. He will come
>   and save you."  Isa 35:5  Then the eyes of the blind shall be opened,
>   and the ears of the deaf unstopped;  Isa 35:6  then shall the lame man
>   leap like a deer, and the tongue of the mute sing for joy. For waters
>   break forth in the wilderness, and streams in the desert;  Isa 35:7 
>   the burning sand shall become a pool, and the thirsty ground springs
>   of water; in the haunt of jackals, where they lie down, the grass
>   shall become reeds and rushes.  Isa 35:8  And a highway shall be
>   there, and it shall be called the Way of Holiness; the unclean shall
>   not pass over it. It shall belong to those who walk on the way; even
>   if they are fools, they shall not go astray.  Isa 35:9  No lion shall
>   be there, nor shall any ravenous beast come up on it; they shall not
>   be found there, but the redeemed shall walk there.  Isa 35:10  And the
>   ransomed of the LORD shall return and come to Zion with singing;
>   everlasting joy shall be upon their heads; they shall obtain gladness
>   and joy, and sorrow and sighing shall flee away.

Considered in that light it may be that Isaiah is introducing a subject of a transformation of the desert into a lavish garden. In fact, I think that is the proper way to view it.

However, though it is speaking of the literal blooming of the desert this should probably be seen as referring to an idealized miraculous eschatology rather than agricultural progress.

Comment: (+1) A good approach to bringing such an opinion-based question back to the text.

Comment: @SteveTaylor-Agriculture in Israel is a highly developed industry: Israel is a major exporter of fresh produce and a world-leader in agricultural technologies despite the fact that the geography of Israel is not naturally conducive to agriculture. More than half of the land area is DESERT, and the climate and lack of water resources do not favor farming.

Answer (score 0):

NIV is a pretty bad translation.  6 "Those who came, whom Jacob caused to take root, Israel flourished and blossomed and they filled the face of the world with fruitage."  Past tense in the Hebrew.

Rashi's commentary: ***Those who came, whom Jacob caused to take root***: Do you not know what I did at first? Those who came to Egypt which Jacob caused to take root, flourished and blossomed there until they filled the face of the world with fruitage.

Clear enough what is being referred to here.

Just read the rest of the chapter:  9 "Therefore, with this shall Jacob's iniquity be atoned for, and this is all the fruit of removing his sin; by making all the altar stones like crushed chalkstones; asherim and sun-images shall not rise.  For a fortified city is solitary, a dwelling is forsaken and abandoned like a pasture; there a calf shall graze, and there he shall lie and consume its branches.

11When its branches dry out, they shall be broken; women shall come and ignite it, for it is not a people of understanding; therefore, its Maker shall not have compassion on it, and He Who formed it shall not grant it favor.  And it shall come to pass on that day, that the Lord shall gather from the flood of the river to the stream of Egypt, and you shall be gathered one by one, O children of Israel.

13 And it shall come to pass on that day, that a great shofar shall be sounded, and those lost in the land of Assyria and those exiled in the land of Egypt shall come and they shall prostrate themselves before the Lord on the holy mount in Jerusalem.

And V2 "On that day, "A vineyard producing wine," sing to it.

Rashi again:  ***On that day***: At the time of the redemption, they shall sing to Israel, “This is a wine producing vineyard. It has yielded its good wine.”

Comment: That "translation" of verse 6 is highly idiosyncratic -- basically plain wrong.